# How to load a customized view on demand on Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

There's a customize view. I want to load it on fragment xml. Which works good.

`FooView.kt`

```
class FooView : ConstraintLayout { }
```

`fragment_login.xml`

```
<xxx>
        <com.abc.def.FooView
         android:id="@+id/otp_view"
        android:layout="@layout/otp_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/systemCyan"
         android:visibility="@{viewModel.otpVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</xxx>
```

This `fooView` might never be used. So I want `fooView` will be init only when used.

I googled and check `ViewStub`, but seems `ViewStub` only load the xml and you can't get the customized view and access the attributes.

I think another solution is creating the fooView programmatically. I haven't tried.

So how to load a customized view on demand in xml? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `ViewStub` like this:

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/yourStubId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/fooViewIdAfterInflated"
    android:layout="@layout/stub_layout" />
```

The `stub_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.name.FooView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**---------------- Extra: How to access your FooView ----------------**

After calling yourViewStubObject.inflate(), it returns a View object which is your `FooView` so generally you can save this view for further usage:

```
val fooView = yourStubId.inflate() as FooView
```

Second option: Add `android:inflateId="@+id/fooViewIdAfterInflated"` so after inflating the ViewStub in the code, this id is available in the view hierarchy and you can find it by calling `findViewById<FooView>(R.id.fooViewIdAfterInflated)` (It's will be null if ViewStub is not inflated)

Comment: how to access the attributes in `FooView` by the view binding which `ViewStub` in?

Comment: I edited it with an extra section

Comment: for the first option, it shows "Cast will always fail "
The second opinion works. thanks!